# python не является внутренней или внешней командой, хотя является таковой

Tags: python, cmd, vim

Через vim открыл python файл. Командой `:!python main.py` попытался запустить на что мне выдало
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если я запускаю через обычную консоль, то все в порядке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит и как через vim выполнить скрипт?

Comment: `ls` в `cmd` это мощно энивей))

Comment: Главное оно работает с cmd https://prnt.sc/106q221 @icYFTL

Comment: В обеих консолях выполните команду `set`. Полученные тексты сравните. Подумайте как отличаются способы запуска `vim` и отдельного `cmd`. Устраните отличия.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy отличие в том, что в вим не та кодировка https://prnt.sc/106rt42. Я поменять значение с помощью `set path=C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32` и это подействовало на единичный запуск, а также ввел `:set encoding=UTF-8` (это вообще не помогло), как сохранить настройки и на следующие разы?

Comment: К сожалению, я вам не помогу. Проблемных мест вижу два: кирилическое имя в пути к программе и 32-хразрядный Питон. Я всегда ставил Питон на Windows в пути без пробелов и кирилицы. Обычно C:\bin\Python. Пути в конфигурации системы правил в панели управления. Если есть возможность, перейдите на 64 бита.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы вытекает из того, что написал @StanislavVolodarskiy. В моем случае это была кодировка, которая не поддерживала кириллицу (Путь до вима содержал `Пользователи`). Пробовал в консоли написать `:set encoding=UTF-8` и тому подобное, но это либо помогало до перезапуска, либо не помогало вообще. Конечно это стоило прописать в `.vimrc`, но так как путь до него содержал кириллицу, то вим его не видел, получается замкнутый круг.

Так как на ноуте (на котором была проблема) не было ничего особо важного, решил переставить винду. При переустановке указал имя на латинице + изменил директорию `Пользователи` в `Users` (Переходите в папку Пользователи, открываете `desktop.ini`, удаляете оттуда все кроме `[.ShellClassInfo]`, сохраняете, возможно был вариант проще, но я использовал такой)

Далее установил vim по [единственному гайду](https://coderoad.ru/18050924/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-VIM), где указано как правильно скачивать вандл на винду, там сказано

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git $HOME\vimfiles\bundle\vundle
Обязательно замените $HOME путем, который мы обнаружили на шаге 1.
```

У меня это сработало, если у вас не сработало, то замените `bundle` на `plugin`.

Это все не относится к вопросу, но эту боль хочу оставить тут, если вдруг опять что не так пойдет.

Comment: А может выбрать путь попроще и использовать *nix операционку? Такого гемара кроме как на винде нигде нету

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch она есть, но пока только в virtualbox (linux mint), не могу пока найти все минусы в установке ее, как основной ОС (поэтому не хочу рисковать). Как минимум мне по работе нужен ворд, так что нет, но это очень заманчиво.